# Error not throwing in workflow

Tags: flowgear

Although an error is being thrown in the child workflow (intended), the parent workflow logs show otherwise. I need that error to be thrown and stop validation so I can display an error message to the user in an external system.
[image: Parent Workflow Logs]
[image: Child Workflow logs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors don't propagate up from iterators. In your example you have regexmatcher which is an iterator (it fires for every match). If you don't need it to fire for every match and just want the first match, use regexmatchone.

If you do need to propagate an error up past an iterator, here's an example of how to do that: http://flowgear.me/s/3Q2N7Wv

Also, although this doesn't directly address your question, http://developers.flowgear.net/kb/Error_Handling is worth looking at.

Comment: I figured out the error throwing the `any error` technique to get past this quirk.